# From where is the transaction fee for a custom token (build on Stellar) that is charged by Stellar Network?

Tags: transactions, fees

From where is the transaction fee for a custom token (build on Stellar) that is charged by Stellar Network? Is it from the custom wallet (I know the only possibility will be in XLM)? From whose Account are these XLMs deducted?

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transaction fee is deducted from the account that acts as the source account for the transaction envelope.

Using the JavaScript SDK, it's the account used to construct the TransactionBuilder:

```
const account = await server.loadAccount(source);
const builder = new stellar.TransactionBuilder(account)
```

Comment: Can we charge a custom fee as our profit from each trade on SDEX? I tried my best to find an option or code but nothing available on stellar documentation.